Demon town unknown movie
This movie was something I watched about eight years ago. It's a horror film, but it might have some elements of comedy in it. The movie begins with a girl and a guy kissing in a car and driving along the highway somewhere in the U.S. They stop the car, say goodbye to each other, and the girl leaves for her home. But at some point, the girl's cousins show up and kill the guy. She runs away crying. Her hometown is some kind of weird neighborhood of sick junkies. Her mother gets beaten up by her mentally ill lover every single day. One day, the girl watches the lover kill her mother in their bed after the mother refuses to be photographed naked. And there's a hole in my memory after that moment. All I know is that this movie is very twisted and that the town is full of demons. Some people come to the town, and at night, everybody gets killed. I remember one demon playing rock guitar - he looked like a skeleton. If anyone knows what movie this is, please let me know - I'd like to watch it again.    

TRAILER PARK OF TERROR. In this movie trailer park girls boyfriend is killed and girl sells soul to stranger for shotgun and guns down whole trailer park. The movie then cuts to a class of kids breaking down at park whose residents are now undead as is the girl. The scene with mom happens in flashback. There's also a huge fat zombie and a China girl zombie. guitar zombie gets blown up. 




Thank you very much, it is the movie I was looking for :D

youre welcome. I know how frustrating it can be to want to find a movie with minimal details.

Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking check mark next to it. Thanx
